# How to update model's property value in Django's shell?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a such a model:

```
class Territory(models.Model):
    voivodeship = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    powiat = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gmina = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comparison_group = models.ForeignKey(ComparisonGroup, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                         related_name='territories', null=True, blank=True)
    partnership = models.ForeignKey(Partnership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    related_name='member_territories', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('voivodeship', 'powiat', 'gmina', 'type')
        verbose_name = 'Jednostka terytorialna'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Jednostki terytorialne'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.type_name} ({self.code})'

    @property
    def code(self):
        if self.voivodeship and self.powiat and self.gmina and self.type:
            return f'{self.voivodeship:02}{self.powiat:02}{self.gmina:02}{self.type}'
        return '--'
```

And now some of those Territories have `code` attribute as `--`, because `self.gmina` and `self.type` were NULL in the DB. Then I updated some rows -- added values for `self.gmina` and `self.type` for some of the territories units and I want to update their `code` attributes. I tried:

```
territories = Territory.objects.filter(type_name='some type name')
for t in territories:
    t.code = <some calculated value>
```

but I get an error kind of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How can I make Django recalculate this `code` value for all items in Territory model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will only query the DB when necessary, so the results of a query or a Model instance are kept until they are updated from the database. To do this, either run the query again and reassign the Model instances or [refresh](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database) the Model with the method `Model.refresh_from_db()`.

The code property is not being stored in the database, it is computed dynamically during the method call. To reevaluate its result you must call the property instead of assigning to it. The error occurs because you are assigning a value to a class property.

```
territories = Territory.objects.filter(type_name='some type name')
for t in territories:
   print(t.code)  # Updated code property
   print(t)       # Updated __str__() call
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Refreshing Model instances is the tip that helped me a lot!